# NVelocity save looping result into JS variable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, nvelocity

I've faced the problem with nvelocity #foreach statement. I'd like to save the collection item properties to the js variable. So I thought that construction like this would cover the issue.

> jQuery('#resendButton').bind('click',
>
> > ```
> >    function (e) {
> >           var failedItems = [#foreach($item in $FailedOrders)
> >                $item.SpecificId#between
> >                ,
> >              #end
> >           ... 
> >    });
> > ```

But it failed. I'm not even able to debug it.
What's the best way to implement such a piece of logic on vm?

Thanks in advance

Comment: At the moment I'm using hidden field to store the loop result. But I guess there's another way. There's always another way, you know.. (=

Comment: It works for me, providing `var failedItems = [123, 321];`. What error are you getting?

Comment: I have no idea. Event handler just disappears.

Comment: I've got a solution that works for me. I removed #between specifier and added splitting logic to controller method.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue here, could you please explain a bit more on how you get over it?

hi I think 
[NVelocity advance lopping syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236300/nvelocity-advance-lopping-syntax/19248126?noredirect=1#19248126)
will help you figure out your issue