# Concat strings with separator in velocity template

Tags: loops, nvelocity

In my velocity template, I want to concat strings delimited by comma(,) using foreach loop.

```
#foreach($field in $MyObject.Fields)
    ${field.Name},
#end
```

This results in an extra comma at the end. How can avoid the last unwanted comma?

PS: I am using NVelocity 0.4.2

Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196828/velocity-do-something-except-in-last-loop-iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't recall where NVelocity 0.4.2 comes from (i.e. Castle Project or the original port), but if it has the foreach looping directives, you can use them. Take a look at this recently asked question on the same topic:

[NVelocity advance lopping syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236300/nvelocity-advance-lopping-syntax)

If it doesn't have support for that, you can use the special `$velocityCount` variable with an `#if` directive to determine if you want a comma or not.